# the proper way of praying qaza namaz?

Tags: salat, salat-qada

I was told to make intention of a qaza namaz instead of the usual intention and offer the prayer the exact same way. after looking up from the internet ..some Muslims offer it in the way ive described and some have mentioned the following way..

1) In Ruku and Sajdah instead of reciting "Subhaana Rabbiyal Azeem" and "Subhaana Rabbiyal A'la" three times, say it only once. But make sure do not leave Ruku poster untill the Meem (M) of Azeem has been said properly. Similarly do not leave the posture of Sajdah until Ala has been said completely. Just make sure to say these Tasbeehaat properly and do not rush.

2) In third and four Rakah of Fard Salah instead of reciting the whole Soorah Fatiha say, "Subhan Allah" three times and go to Ruku, . Make sure "Subhan Allah" has been recited three times properly, do not rush. This exeption is only for Fard. In third rakah of Witr it's a must to recite full Soorah Fatiha followed by at least three ayahs of Quran or a soorah (as we usually do in first and second rakah).

3) In last Qaidah (when we sit for Attahyyat) before Salam, after Attahyyat instead of full Durood and Dua just say, "Allah Humma Salle Ala Sayedena Mohammad Wa Aalihi", then finish the Salat with Salam. Dua is not a must here.

4) In Witr, instead of full Dua-e-Qunoot just say "Rabbigh Fir Lee" one or three times.

I want to know the correct way of performing qaza prayers...is the second method for those who have to make up for the prayers they have missed for years?

Comment: There's no difference between praying on time or qada`. I don't know where you've got this information from or are just mixing things?

Comment: If a Fard or Wajib prayer could not be offered at a prescribed time due to some reason,  it is said to have been rendered Qada' or missed..I want to know the correct way of performing it.
https://www.alquranclasses.com/qaza-salah-method-to-perform-quickly/
https://www.sherekhudahazratali.com/2015/04/how-to-perform-qaza-namaz-of-life-time.html
http://www.naqshbandia.info/naqshbandia_sardaria/Fiqah_Imam_Shariah.htm    (look under Difference between Ladies and Men's Salah)
https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-pray-the-Qaza-Namaz

Comment: These are all without any evidences. And search for "Qada" prayer instead of "Qaza".

Comment: Note that the posted links speak about a fast solution for people who have a lot of missed prayers which is a special case within the topic of qada' prayers. Note that some scholars say either one misses a prayer due to sleep or forgetfulness or one intentionally miss it the later case is a big sin and there's no qada' for that. As there's no ruling in Qur'an or sunnah for this case. However the majority of scholars say one can pray qada' or concentrate on sunnah or nafl prayers instead after doing repentance.

Comment: You should add these links to your post by using the **edit** link at the bottom if you are registred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all what you have mentioned is nothing very special. You could pray your prayers which you pray on time in the same manner. As the mentioned "reductions" are what we may call the necessary or the short cuts of the better dhikr's one need to perform in the prayer. Alhamdullilah our prophet tought us different ways and wordings for dhikr's in each almost each position of the prayer. Scholars for example came to a agreed that the minimum amount of verses to recite after al-Fatihah is three verses one may even recite ayat al-Kursi alone or any longer verse one could memorize.
So basically as Medi1 said there's no difference in how to pray a prayer on time and one that one missed due whatever reason may it be halal or a sinful reason.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to say all the rakaats as you would usually say them. Only in the niyat do you mention that the salat is qaza